# Ставится ли запятая перед второй основой в обороте с "что"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

Он хотел верить в то, что сдаст экзамен(,) и Мэри согласится на его предложение.

Ему казалось, что Мэри удалось с этим разобраться(,) и она могла торжественно закончить эту главу своей жизни.

Answer (score 1):

*Он хотел верить в то, **что сдаст экзамен и Мэри согласится на его предложение.***

*Ему казалось, **что Мэри удалось с этим разобраться и (теперь) она могла торжественно закончить эту главу своей жизни.***

В обоих случаях это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) **с однородными изъяснительными придаточными.**

Главная часть в каждом предложении (*хотел верить, казалось*) относится к обоим придаточным, то есть грамматика этих СПП одинаковая.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

3. Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) **запятая не ставится:** Отец мой говорил, что он не видывал таких хлебов и что нынешний год урожай отличный (Акс.); Чудилось, будто корчуют сразу весь лес и выдираемые из земли корни и сама земля стонут и вопят от боли (Фед.)